# Как удалить символ в строке без создания новой переменной?

Tags: javascript

```
let numbers = [];
numbers += 12452;
console.log(numbers); // 12452
```

Как сделать так, чтобы numbers стало равно 1245? Через replace() создаётся новая переменная, а это не нужно. Slice() также создаёт новую строку. Вряд-ли в js нету нужного мне метода.

Comment: Такого метода не будет в принципе, потому что в JS строки - это не мутируемый тип данных.

Comment: Первые две строки вызывают только один вопрос: а вы вообще понимаете что пишете?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, очевидно, это хитрый способ приведения числа к строке

Comment: Если экономить на создании строк, то стоит сразу записывать в строку без последней цифры